# How check facebook user is fan or not of my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I created a Facebook App and I would like to check whether the current facebook user is fan or not of my facebook page (using Javascript). This verification must be done into the facebook app.

Best regards

---

I was trying the code:

```
function isEmptyObj(obj) {
for(var prop in obj) {
    alert(prop);
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        return false;
}

return true;
```

}

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

          FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP_ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
          var page_id = "PAGE_ID";

              FB.api('/me/likes/' + page_id,function(response) {

                if( response.data ) {
                    if( !isEmptyObj(response.data) )
                        alert('You are a fan!');
                    else
                        alert('Not a fan!');
                } else {
                    alert('ERROR!');
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: Where should I send the bill? ;)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how things work on the site.  You are going to have to show that you have **at least** tried something.  People are not going to do your work for you.

Comment: The functionality that you desire is covered in the basic documentation on Facebook.  You should try read over that first before coming and asking here.

Comment: Hi Lix, your comments are not necessary. We are posting here because we are looking for solutions

Comment: **We are very willing to help and provide solutions.**  But you have to show that you put some effort into solving this before posting it here.  Have you read the documentation at all? There is no real question here... It just sounds like you are looking for someone else to do the research and work for you.  [That's not how we do things around here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172936)

Comment: You are WRONG, could be that my post was too short but you CAN NOT mention that my intention is that you work for me

Comment: Including the code you are using is what I was talking about... you gave no references to what you have tried or what errors/problems you faced.  Your update makes this post much much better.

Comment: What (if any) data are you getting in `response.data`?

Comment: The response.data is undefined. (If I post it is because there is something wrong Lix). My intension is show to the user  a message "Like us to enter" before access to the app (using facebook js sdk)

Comment: Have you requested the `user_likes` permission prior to executing this query?

Comment: I think the problem is that the app is not assigned to any page. My test app https://apps.facebook.com/429638633725164/ and the example  https://www.facebook.com/MarriottHotelsUK/app_349066788486297

Comment: Please answer Lix’ question …!

Comment: Yes, I used FB.login(function (){}, {perms:'user_likes'}); but this code invoke the login dialog.

Comment: You have to login to get the permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check the `like` status of a user with the JavaScript SDK, you'll need to have the user logged into your application with the `user_likes` permission.

The alternative (without requiring a user to login or request permissions) is to use a server side language to parse the [`Signed Request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) that Facebook passes to any application running inside Facebook.  The parsed Signed Request will contain a boolen value indicating whether or not the user has liked the page.  That value will only be present if the application you are using has been embedded on a page as a Page tab application.

Comment: Thanks Lix, I used the "Signed Request" method on the server side and it is working fine. I was looking for a JavaScript SDK solution but there is no way :(

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript but that would mean you'd have to expose your `app_secret` to your users.  That is very dangerous and not recommended...

Comment: I hope you now understand what I meant by my first comments and that you didn't take offence from them.  We are here to help people but they have to try help themselves first.